# Создать файл, содержащий сведения о рейсах автобусов и технического состояния. На java

Tags: java

Каждая запись содержит поля: номер рейса, пункт
отправления, пункт назначения, время поездки, количество свободных
мест, сведение о техническом состоянии. Количество записей
произвольное. Написать программу, выводящую на экран следующую
информацию:
- список автобусов, у которых технические неисправности;
- список автобусов с количеством свободных мест для указанного
пункта назначения;

Я смог сделать только это. И как вывести мне 2 нижеследующих пункта? Я должен вывести его из файла?

```
BufferedReader br = null;
        try{
            File file = new File("Transport.txt");

            if(!file.exists())
                file.createNewFile();

            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
            pw.println("Номер рейса:");
            pw.println("Пункт отправления:");
            pw.println("Пункт назначения:");
            pw.println("Время поездки:");
            pw.println("Свободные места:");
            pw.println("Техническое состояние:");
            pw.close();

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Transport.txt"));
            String line;
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }finally{
            try{
                br.close();
            }catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("Error: " + e);`введите сюда код`
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Начну с главного - заканчивайте (а лучше не начинайте) писать процедурный код. Ваше описание задачи не очень конкретиезировано (например, в части вывода в файл непонятно, какой формат данных должен быть), но даже в этом случае вполне понятно, что у нас есть некая предметная область, которая представлена в данном случае одной сущностью, которая и должна описывать автобусные рейсы. Это значит, что для начала нам нужно создать класс, который будет хранить в себе всю необходимую информацию о автобусном рейсе. Выглядит это так:

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class BusFlight implements CsvStore{

    private final static String DELIMITER = ";";
    public final static String CONTENT = Stream.of("Номер рейса", "Пункт отправления", 
            "Пункт назначения", "Время поездки", "Свободные места", "Техническое состояние", "\r\n")
            .collect(Collectors.joining(DELIMITER));

    private Integer number;
    private String source;
    private String destination;
    private Integer travelTimeMinute;
    private Integer freePlace;
    private Boolean technicalCondition;

    public Integer getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(Integer number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getSource() {
        return source;
    }

    public void setSource(String source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public String getDestination() {
        return destination;
    }

    public void setDestination(String destination) {
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    public Integer getTravelTimeMinute() {
        return travelTimeMinute;
    }

    public void setTravelTimeMinute(Integer travelTimeMinute) {
        this.travelTimeMinute = travelTimeMinute;
    }

    public Integer getFreePlace() {
        return freePlace;
    }

    public void setFreePlace(Integer freePlace) {
        this.freePlace = freePlace;
    }

    public Boolean getTechnicalCondition() {
        return technicalCondition;
    }

    public void setTechnicalCondition(Boolean technicalCondition) {
        this.technicalCondition = technicalCondition;
    }

    @Override
    public String toCsv() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        return sb.append(number).append(DELIMITER).append(source).append(DELIMITER)
                .append(destination).append(DELIMITER).append(travelTimeMinute).append(DELIMITER)
                .append(freePlace).append(DELIMITER).append(technicalCondition).append(DELIMITER).toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BusFlights{" + "number=" + number + ", source=" + source + ", destination=" + destination + 
                ", travelTimeMinute=" + travelTimeMinute + ", freePlace=" + freePlace + ", technicalCondition=" + technicalCondition + '}';
    }

}
```

Разумеется, мы добавим геттеры и сеттеры, чтобы иметь доступ к нашим полям (методы equels, hashcode я не писал, т.к. в нашем случае пользы от них не будет, но по хорошему это делать надо всегда). Кроме, того мы переопределим метод toString, чтобы определить вид, в котором будет выводится информация о рейсе в консоль. И последнее, нам нужно не забыть о создании файла. Я выбрал csv-формат из-за простоты. Мы запишем все поля с разделителем ";". Это значит , что нам нужен метод который соберет информацию об своем рейсе в строку для нашего будущего csv. Отлично, добавим метод toCsv(). 
Наш класс готов, теперь мы имеем возможность создавать экземпляры этого класса,  в которых и будет хранится информация о рейсах.
Перейдем к фильтрации и записи. Поскольку в этом случае нам надо иметь дело не с одним объектом ранее созданного класса, а с множеством таких объектов, я создам класс-сервис, он должен уметь выводить в консоль переданный ему список объектов, выполняя фильтрацию по определенному условию, а также писать в файл в формате csv. Но я бы хотел иметь возможность переиспользовать свой класс-сервис для работы со списками других сущностей (моделей). Поэтому я имплементирую интерфейс для класса-модели с единственным методом - toCsv(), который уже реализован в моем классе-модели. Теперь я создаю класс-сервис и типизирую его дженериком, наследуемым от нашего интерфейса и реализую нужных мне 2 метода : вывод в консоль с фильтрацией и сохранения в csv. Теперь мой класс сервис может работать с любой моделью, которая будет имплементировать созданный мной интерфейс, а не только с классом BusFlight.
Выглядит наш сервис довольно просто, а интерфейс еще проще:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface CsvStore {
    public String toCsv();
}
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class BusFlightService <T extends CsvStore> {

    public void filterAndPrint(List<T> busFlightsList, Predicate <T> predicate) {
        busFlightsList.stream().filter(predicate).forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public void writeToFile(String path, List<T> busFlightsList, String content) throws IOException {
        String result = busFlightsList.stream().map(e -> e.toCsv()).collect(Collectors.joining("\r\n"));
        Files.write(Paths.get(path), (content+result).getBytes());
    }

}
```

Вот и все, теперь осталось откуда-то взять список рейсов. Я сгенерирую этот список, заполнив его случайными значениями, после чего передам мой список экземпляру класса-сервиса , который выведет мне в консоль нужную отфильтрованную информацию и сохранит все в файл. 
Выглядит это так:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.UUID;

public class Main {

    private static final int NUMB_BUS_FLIGHTS = 50;
    private static final int FREE_PLACES = 5;
    private static final String FILE_NAME = "Transport.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        //создаем список рейсов и заполняем его случайными значениями
        List<BusFlight> busFlightsList = new ArrayList<>(NUMB_BUS_FLIGHTS);
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMB_BUS_FLIGHTS; i++) {
            BusFlight busFlights = new BusFlight();
            busFlights.setNumber(i);
            busFlights.setSource(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            busFlights.setDestination(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            busFlights.setTravelTimeMinute(randomGenerator(15, 180));
            busFlights.setFreePlace(randomGenerator(0, 50));
            busFlights.setTechnicalCondition(randomGenerator(0, 1) == 0);
            busFlightsList.add(busFlights);
        }

        //создаем экземпляр сервисногшо класса для работы со списками рейсов
        BusFlightService <BusFlight> busFlightService = new BusFlightService();

        //выводим списки с фильтрацией (тех.неисправные и с определенным количеством свободных мест)
        System.out.println("СПИСОК РЕЙСОВ, ГДЕ У АВСТОБУСОВ ЕСТЬ ТЕХ.НЕИСПРАВНОСТИ");
        busFlightService.filterAndPrint(busFlightsList, bus -> !bus.getTechnicalCondition());
        System.out.println("**************************************************");

        System.out.println("СПИСОК РЕЙСОВ, ГДЕ КОЛИЧЕСТВО СВОБОДНЫХ МЕСТ " + FREE_PLACES);
        busFlightService.filterAndPrint(busFlightsList, bus -> bus.getFreePlace() == FREE_PLACES);
        System.out.println("**************************************************");

        //записываем список всех рейсов в файл
        busFlightService.writeToFile(FILE_NAME, busFlightsList, BusFlight.CONTENT);

    }

    private static int randomGenerator(int min, int max) {
        Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        return min + rnd.nextInt(max - min + 1);
    }

}
```

Удачи , если есть вопросы - пишите, постараюсь ответить.

Comment: А нельзя как-нибудь попроще, слишком сложно! Тема файлы и строки.

Comment: @Baiel тема "файлы и строки" в любом случае идет после темы "ооп". вы уже должны знать, что такое интерфейсы, наследование, переопределение методов и т.д. тут наследование простейшее - один интерфейс и один класс-наследник, один переопределенный метод. куда еще проще? попробуйте сффрмулировать вопрос точнее. что именно непонятно? идите поэтапно. начните с класса - модели, разберите его и задайте все вопросы по этому классу итд. вы реализовали только запись и то непонятно чего (тольок заголовков), потратив 50 строк кода. думаете это проще?

Comment: СПИСОК РЕЙСОВ, ГДЕ У АВСТОБУСОВ ЕСТЬ ТЕХ.НЕИСПРАВНОСТИ
BusFlights{number=0, source=3fa2d444-abfb-4ff2-a9fa-06ce66d25ea0, destination=3bb8619e-c7fb-4fa9-beb6-991c443c8c00, travelTimeMinute=167, freePlace=11, technicalCondition=false}

Comment: СПИСОК РЕЙСОВ, ГДЕ КОЛИЧЕСТВО СВОБОДНЫХ МЕСТ 5
**************************************************

Comment: Мне выводит это

Comment: @Baiel все правильно, запускайте несколько раз и результат будет каждый раз разный, потому что каждый раз генерируется рандомный список. каждый раз количество свободных мест разное и количество сломанных автобусов тоже. весь список сохраняется в файл, можете пересмотреть

Comment: source=2b061c03-eaea-4afd-b21e-e6e5659f356b, destination=f440d3a2-b13e-47b1-9d4f-a4e5238427f1, А что это он не выводит source и destination или так должно быть? И список рейсов с свободными местами он не выводит

Comment: И еще там где интерфейс CsvStore конфликтует с BusFlightService за название файла, если я убираю public в BusFlightService то все в порядке.

Comment: @Baiel в джаве есть правило - один публичный класс - один файл. если разнести по разным файлам , как это и должно быть, то не придется ничего убирать. обратите внимание на заголовок  СПИСОК РЕЙСОВ, ГДЕ КОЛИЧЕСТВО СВОБОДНЫХ МЕСТ 5. этот список выводит рейсы, где 5 свободных мест. вы можете это легко менять. чтобы узнать рейсы, где есть свободные места измените в мейн классе эти строки private static final int FREE_PLACES = 0; и еще одну  строку busFlightService.filterAndPrint(busFlightsList, bus -> bus.getFreePlace() > FREE_PLACES);

Comment: @Baiel в сервис передается предикат, т.е. вы можете фильтровать список по любому условию, не изменяя сервис. за это отвечает именно эта строка busFlightService.filterAndPrint(busFlightsList, bus -> bus.getFreePlace() > FREE_PLACES); в этой строке есть лямбда bus -> bus.getFreePlace() > FREE_PLACES. это означает, что я вызываю геттер и получаю количество свободных мест (bus.getFreePlace() ) , после чего сравниваю с переменной FREE_PLACES. мы изменили ее на 0. поэтому в случае, если количество свободных мест больео 0 му увидим рейс в списке

Comment: @Baiel source=2b061c03-eaea-4afd-b21e-e6e5659f356b, destination=f440d3a2-b13e-47b1-9d4f-a4e5238427f1 - это просто случайно генерируемая строка текста. у меня нет словарей или реальных маршрутов, чтобы подставит названия станций или городов. поэтому я генерирую случайные строки (считайте что это псевдоназвания городов). вопрос ведь не в этом. вы хотите отфильтровать список по кол-ву свободных мест и произвести сохранение. где брать список вы вопросе не указали

Comment: Извините там где FREE_PLACES = 0 у нас в консоли ничего не должен вывести так? Так как свободных мест нету. Или же наоборот.

Comment: @Baiel у вас есть 2 параметра FREE_PLACES = 0 и лямбда bus.getFreePlace() > FREE_PLACES. в этом случае количество свободных мест больше 0