# Создать файл, содержащий сведения о рейсах автобусов и технического состояния

Tags: java

1. По условию вывести список только тех автобусов у которых технические неисправности.
2. По условию вывести список только тех автобусов у которых свободные места для указанного место назначения.Например вводим с консоли место назначение и до того место назначения в каких автобусах есть свободные места нужно эти выводить.

Я смог реализовать только файл и вывожу только общее. Я не могу никак реализовать 2 условия выше. Вот что я смог реализовать:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Bus {
    public static ArrayList<List> list5 = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        try {
            File file = new File("Transport.txt");
            if (!file.exists()) file.createNewFile();//если файла не существует, то создаем
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(file);//выделяем память для PrintWriter
            //            Автобус №1
            printWriter.println(6);//номер рейса
            printWriter.println("Алматинка");//пункт отправления
            printWriter.println("7 мкр");//пункт назначения
            printWriter.println(45);//время поездки
            printWriter.println(20);//свободные места
            printWriter.println("Исправное");//техническое состояние
            //            Автобус №2
            printWriter.println(9);//номер рейса
            printWriter.println("Фрунзе");//пункт отправления
            printWriter.println("Горького");//пункт назначения
            printWriter.println(50);//время поездки
            printWriter.println(10);//свободные места
            printWriter.println("Неисправное");//техническое состояние
            //            Автобус №3
            printWriter.println(10);//номер рейса
            printWriter.println("Джал");//пункт отправления
            printWriter.println("Абая");//пункт назначения
            printWriter.println(25);//время поездки
            printWriter.println(0);//свободные места
            printWriter.println("Исправное");//техническое состояние
            //            Автобус №4
            printWriter.println(1);//номер рейса
            printWriter.println("10 мкр");//пункт отправления
            printWriter.println("Турсунбаева");//пункт назначения
            printWriter.println(55);//время поездки
            printWriter.println(25);//свободные места
            printWriter.println("Исправное");//техническое состояние
            //            Автобус №5
            printWriter.println(3);//номер рейса
            printWriter.println("Панфилова");//пункт отправления
            printWriter.println("6 мкр");//пункт назначения
            printWriter.println(30);//время поездки
            printWriter.println(20);//свободные места
            printWriter.println("Неисправное");//техническое состояние
            //            Автобус №6
            printWriter.println(4);//номер рейса
            printWriter.println("Московская");//пункт отправления
            printWriter.println("Ахунбаева");//пункт назначения
            printWriter.println(60);//время поездки
            printWriter.println(12);//свободные места
            printWriter.println("Неисправное");//техническое состояние
            printWriter.close();//закрываем PrintWriter
            //для чтения создаем BufferReader
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Transport.txt"));
            String line;
            //пока есть что для чтения,все строки добавляем в массив
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                list.add(line);
            }

            int size = 6;
            for (int start = 0; start < list.size(); start += size) {
                int end = Math.min(start + size, list.size());
                List sublist = list.subList(start, end);
                list5.add(sublist);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);//При ошибке
        } finally {
            try {
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + e);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < list5.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(list5.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println("---------------------------------");
        Tech();
        System.out.println("----------------------------------");
        Free();
    }

    public static void Tech() {
        for (int i = 0; i < list5.size(); i++) {
            String a;
            a = list5.get(i).get(5).toString();
            {
                if (list5.get(i).contains(a)) {
                    System.out.println("Номер рейса " + list5.get(i).get(0) + " : " + list5.get(i).get(5));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Free() {
        for (int i = 0; i < list5.size(); i++) {
            String c;
            c = list5.get(i).get(2).toString();

            if (list5.get(i).contains(c)) {
                System.out.println("До улицы " + list5.get(i).get(2) + " : " + list5.get(i).get(4) + " свободных мест " + " Номер рейса " + list5.get(i).get(0));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: у вас один курс на всю группу, поэтому учимся пользоваться поисковиком, лично я отвечал на этот вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1120680/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%9d/1120992#1120992

Comment: Как бы да, но нет. Это не то что мне нужно.

Comment: а чем это отличается?

Comment: Вы знаете как реализовать правильно эти 2 условия?

Comment: Потому что это просто работа с файлами и их вывод. А у вас целый сервис.

Comment: вы посмотрите внимательно на условие и на реализацию для начала

Comment: В вашем коде или в моем?

Comment: Так вы сможете реализовать первые два условия, ибо у меня никак не получается?

Comment: я не просто могу, я это уже сделал и предоставил вам ссылку на ответ. за исключением того, что у меня выводит просто список свободных мест. причем сделал это с описанием и с использованием ооп.

Comment: Нет мне нужен новый код, а не старый. Тот слишком сложный, не понятный для меня.

Comment: Помогите мне решить задачу с 2 условиями пожалуйста.

Comment: Так вы поможете мне реализовать или нет?

Comment: я могу помочь вам разобраться в нормальной реализации задачи, если у вас, разумеется, есть желание научиться. а писать процедурный код, к сожалению, вы и сами научитесь. я пересмотрел условие. задача решена один в один (я просто сразу не увидел,что у вас нет промежуточных станций движения). посему у вас есть готовое решение с подробным описанием и возможность задавать любые вопросы. я не совсем понимаю, какой помощи вы еще хотите?